# Why will this not return the area?

Tags: java, arrays

```
class TestShapes  {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // creates the scanner class
    System.out.print("Enter the numer of shapes: "); // asks user for input
    int N = input.nextInt(); // stores the user input as N
    Shape [] myShape = new Shape[N]; // will create as many shapes (N) in an array 
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the choice (Square, Rectangle, Circle):");
        int select = input.nextInt();
        if(select == 1)
        {
            //user wanted a Square
            System.out.print("Enter the color: ");
            String c = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the side length of the square: ");
            double s  = input.nextDouble();
            myShape[i] = new Square(c,s);

        }
        else if(select == 2)
        {
            //user wanted a Rectangle
            System.out.print("Enter the color: ");
            String c = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the length of the rectangle: ");
            double l = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter the width of the rectangle: ");
            double w = input.nextDouble();
            myShape[i] = new Rectangle(c,l,w);

        }
        else if(select == 3)
        {
            //user wanted a Circle
            System.out.print("Enter the color: ");
            String c = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the radius of the circle: ");
            double r = input.nextDouble();
            myShape[i] = new Circle(c,r);

        }
}
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++) //this will print the details
    {
        System.out.println("\nShape "+ (i+1)+ ":");
        myShape[i].print();
    }
}

}

class Shape {

 String color;
 double area;

public Shape(){ // default constructor
    color = "red";
}

public Shape(String c){ // constructor
    color =c;
}

public String getColor(){ //accessors
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String c){//mutators
    color=c;
}
//print method
public void print()
{
    System.out.println("Color: "+ getColor());
}
 public double area(){
    return area;
}
}

class Square extends Shape{ // inherits from the shape class

double sideLength;

public Square(){//default constructor
    super();
    sideLength = 1;
}

public Square(String c, double s){ //constructor
    super(c);
    sideLength = s;
}

public double getSideLength(){//accessor
    return sideLength;
}

public void setSideLength(double s){//mutator
    sideLength = s;
}

public double area(){
    return sideLength * sideLength; //calculates the area of the square
}

public void print()
{
    super.print();
    System.out.println("Side length: " + getSideLength()
        + "\nArea: " + area);

}
}

class Rectangle extends Shape{// inherits from the shape class
    double length;
    double width;

public Rectangle(){//default constructor
    super();
    length = 1;
    width = 1;
}

public Rectangle(String c, double l, double w){ //constructor
    super(c);
    length = l;
    width = w;
}

public double getLength(){//accessor
    return length;
}

public double getWidth(){//accessor
    return width;
}

public void setLength(double l){//mutator
    length = l;
}
public void setSideLength(double w){//mutator
    width = w;
}

public double area(){
    return length * width; //calculates thea area of the rectangle
}

public void print()
{ // prints out the information
    super.print();
    System.out.println("Length: " + getLength() + "\nWidth:"+ getWidth() + "\nArea: "+ area);

}

}

class Circle extends Shape{// inherits from the shape class

    double radius;
public Circle(String c, double r){//default constructor
    super(c);
    radius = 1;
}

public Circle(double r){ //constructor
    super();
    radius = r;
}

public double getRadius(){//accessor
    return radius;
}

public void setRadius(double r){//mutator
    radius = r;
}

public void print()
{ // prints out the information
    super.print();
    System.out.println("Radius: " + getRadius() + "\nArea:"+ area);

}
public double area(){
return 3.14159 * (radius * radius); //calculates the area of the circle
}   
}
```

I have tried every which way to get the Area to return and no matter what I try it will not. Everything else works fine, it prints out everything correctly but not the area. any advice?

Enter the number of shapes: 1
Enter the choice (Square, Rectangle, Circle):
1
Enter the color: red
Enter the side length of the square: 2

Shape 1:
Color: red
Side length: 2.0
Area: 0.0

Answer (score 1):

You are not calculating the area  , you should use area() in your print statment

```
 System.out.println("Side length: " + getSideLength() + "\nArea: " + area());
```

Comment: the area is calculated in each of the classes (square, rectangle, circle) that extend shape. they are at the bottom of each class. it is returned after calculating. Example from the code above `public double area(){
    return sideLength * sideLength; //calculates the area of the square
} `

Comment: @154 guy . correct , but you are calling the variable area in your print statement , not the function area()

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out uninitialized variable `area` instead of calling the function `area()`.

```
System.out.println("Side length: " + getSideLength() + "\nArea: " + area());
```

That should work, but you should avoid using functions and variables of the same name. `getArea()` would be a better function name.

Comment: this worked, thank you. ill use that for future refrence

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if they helped solve your problem.